# Find and rename files using a Python script

Tags: python, datetime, find, command, rename

I am new to Python coding so here a question. I want to find files that are called "untitled" with any kind of extension, e.g. jpg, indd, psd. Then rename them to the date of the current day.

I have tried the following:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez"):
    if file.endswith("untitled.*"):
        print(file)
```

When I run the script, nothing happens.

Comment: Don't you mean `if file.startswith("untitled")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html?highlight=glob.glob#glob.glob) function more useful in this situation:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez/untitled.*"):
    print(file)
```

Your function does not print anything as there are probably no files ending with `.*` in the name. The `glob.glob()` function will carry out the file expansion for you.

You can then use this to do your file renaming as follows:

```
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for source_name in glob.glob("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez/untitled.*"):
    path, fullname = os.path.split(source_name)
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fullname)
    target_name = os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(current_day, ext))
    os.rename(source_name, target_name)
```

A Python `datetime` object can be used to get you a suitable timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Python string comparator does not support wildcards.  You can search for "untitled." anywhere in the text:

```
import os
    for file in os.listdir("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez"):
        if "untitled." in file:
            print(file)
```

keep in mind that this will include any file that has "untitled." at any location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try with this approach

```
import os
directoryPath = '/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez'
lstDir = os.walk(directoryPath) 
for root, dirs, files in lstDir:
  for fichero in files:        
    (filename, extension) = os.path.splitext(fichero)
    if filename.find('untitle') != -1: # == 0 if starting with untitle
         os.system('mv '+directoryPath+filename+extension+' '+directoryPath+'$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")'+filename+extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez"):
   if(file.startswith("untitled")):
      os.rename(file, datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y") + "." +  file.split(".")[-1])
```